# Spring Security without web.xml

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, servlet-3.0

What is the recommended way to add Spring Security to a web application that is using Spring's new `WebApplicationInitializer` interface instead of the web.xml file?  I'm looking for the equivalent of:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
```

**UPDATE** 
The provided answers are reasonable but they both assume that I've got a `servletContext` instance.  I've looked through the hierarchy of `WebApplicationInitializer`s and I don't see any access to the servlet context unless I choose to override one of Spring's initializer methods.  `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer.registerServletFilter` seems like the sensible choice but it doesn't default to URL pattern mapping and I'd hate to change filter registration for everything if there is a better way.

Comment: When you create your class that implements WebApplicationInitializer you will override "void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)" with what was previously in your web.xml.  The ServletContext will be passed to your WebApplicationInitializer implementation.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the way that I have done it:

```
container.addFilter("springSecurityFilterChain", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
                    .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

container is an instance of `ServletContext`

Answer (score 17):

The [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#abstractsecuritywebapplicationinitializer) answers this question and the solution depends on whether or not you are using Spring Security in conjunction with Spring or Spring MVC.

#### Using Spring Security without Spring or Spring MVC

If you are **not** using Spring Security with Spring or Spring MVC (i.e. you do not have an existing `WebApplicationInitializer`) then you need to provide the following additional class:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {
        super(SecurityConfig.class);
    }
}
```

Where `SecurityConfig` is your Spring Security Java configuration class.

#### Using Spring Security with Spring or Spring MVC

If you are using Spring Security with Spring or Spring MVC (i.e. you have an existing `WebApplicationInitializer`) then firstly you need to provide the following additional class:

```
import org.springframework.security.web.context.*;

public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {
}
```

Then you need to ensure that your Spring Security Java configuration class, `SecurityConfig` in this example, is declared in your existing Spring or Spring MVC `WebApplicationInitializer`. For example:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.*;

public class MvcWebApplicationInitializer
    extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SecurityConfig.class};
    }

    // ... other overrides ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
Dynamic securityFilter = servletContext.addFilter(AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME, DelegatingFilterProxy.class);
securityFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class), false, "/*");
```

**EnumSet.allOf(DispatcherType.class)** to be sure that you add a mapping not only for default DispatcherType.REQUEST, but for **DispatcherType.FORWARD**, etc...

Comment: To be independent of the name of the filter chain it seems to be more appropriate to use `AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.DEFAULT_FILTER_NAME` instead of `springSecurityFilterChain`.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of work, I've discovered that it's actually quite simple:

```java
public class Initialiser extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class< ? >[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RootConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class< ? >[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        return new Filter[] { new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain") };
    }
}
```

The most important thing, though, is that you **must** have a root context (e.g. `RootConfig` in this case), and that must contain a reference to all the spring security information.

Thus, my `RootConfig` class:

```java
@ImportResource("classpath:spring/securityContext.xml")
@ComponentScan({ "com.example.authentication", "com.example.config" })
@Configuration
public class RootConfig {

    @Bean
    public DatabaseService databaseService() {
        return new DefaultDatabaseService();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler authExceptionMapping() {
        final ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler emafh = new ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();
        emafh.setDefaultFailureUrl("/loginFailed");
        final Map<String, String> mappings = new HashMap<>();
        mappings.put(CredentialsExpiredException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/change_password");
        emafh.setExceptionMappings(mappings);
        return emafh;
    }
}
```

And `spring/securityContext.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>

    <!-- Secured pages -->
    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <security:form-login default-target-url="/index" login-processing-url="/login_form" login-page="/login" authentication-failure-handler-ref="authExceptionMapping" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider ref="customAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

I could not get it to work if I merged the `RootConfig` and `WebAppConfig` classes into just `WebAppConfig` and had the following:

```java
@Override
protected Class< ? >[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected Class< ? >[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[] { WebAppConfig.class };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public class SIServerSecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        Dynamic registration = servletContext.addFilter("TenantServletFilter", TenantServletFilter.class);
        EnumSet<DispatcherType> dispatcherTypes = getSecurityDispatcherTypes();
        registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), false, "/*");
    }

}
```

This scenario is for executing a filter before executing other filters.
If you want to execute a filter after other filers pass `true` in `registration.addMappingForUrlPatterns(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.REQUEST), true, "/*");`. Also check the DispatcherType ASYNC, FORWARD etc.

Answer (score 0):

Faced with the same problem. Merge RootConfig and WebAppConfig - not best way - because this i did not try this solution. Tried all other solutions - everty time got "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error filterStart". After some work, got something like this:

```
    FilterRegistration.Dynamic enc= servletContext.addFilter("encodingFilter",
            new CharacterEncodingFilter());
    encodingFilter .setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
    encodingFilter .setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
    encodingFilter .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");
```

But is not working with DelegatingFilterProxy(). Continue finding for best common solution for all filters.

**UPDATE:**
I did it.

So, the main issue is: if you want add filters using java config, especially if you want to add security filter, such as DelegatingFilterProxy, then you have to create WebAppSecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ImportResource("classpath:security.xml")
public class WebAppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
}
```

In this case i create WebAppSecurityConfig and make import resource ("security.xml").
This let me to do that in Initializer class:

```
servletContext.addFilter("securityFilter", new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain"))
            .addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, false, "/*");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is related to those interested in Spring Boot with security: You don't need anything, Spring Boot picks up the @components and solves the other issues