# Any examples for configuring spring-security-oauth2 without SpringBoot/SpringMVC and using programmatical registering on Jetty/Jersy (xml-less)?

Tags: java, spring, jersey, java-8, spring-security-oauth2

I have an app that runs a jetty server that registers some ja-rs endpoints by means of jersey handlers. I am using Spring-security-oauth2 but I don't see the way of connecting the context with the jersey dispatcher/filter/servlet.

Comment: Care to explain downvoter?

Comment: Please take a look at the Help Center to understand [What topics you can ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I've been searching the answer for 3 hours, I don't know what else I can do but ask here fo some enlightment

Comment: Consider asking on chat. Stack Overflow is not the place for tutorial and off site resource requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it! I finally found this as the actual clue to know how to work it. I should had ask for Jetty more than Jersey, and spring-security in particular instead of spring-security-oauth2

[Spring Security without web.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14205140/spring-security-without-web-xml)

and also

[Embedded Jetty doesn't recognise Spring MVC Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927761/embedded-jetty-doesnt-recognise-spring-mvc-security)